# What does "! -f" mean in make file?

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel

I don't understand the below make file command line. What does "[ ! -f" stands for?

```
[ ! -f $(KERNEL_OUT)/drivers/eu.ko ] || \
    cp $(KERNEL_OUT)/drivers/eu.ko $(TARGET_OUT)/lib/
```

Comment: The commands in a Makefile are shell commands, and are (with rare exceptions) not specific to use by make. On a typical system (and by that I mean one that uses bash), you can run `help [` to find a brief mention of the fact that it's just like the `test` command, and `help test` to find more info.

Comment: thanks, i knew that, somehow i thought that it may related with make

Comment: [ command evaluates conditional according to help, this line still make no sense on me
if file does not exist or copy file to blabla ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already figured out from the documentation that

> ```
> [ ! -f $(KERNEL_OUT)/drivers/eu.ko ]
> ```

tests that the file does not exist, and you already know that

> ```
> cp $(KERNEL_OUT)/drivers/eu.ko $(TARGET_OUT)/lib/
> ```

copies the file. Therefore, `[ ! -f ... ] || cp ...` copies the file only if it exists: it can be read as "the file does not exist, or else the file will be copied".

Normally you might write it as

```
[ -f ... ] && cp ...
```

However, if the file does not exist, this would exit with a non-zero status code: the status code would be zero only if the file exists and was successfully copied. The goal here is to not treat the non-existence of the file as an error condition, so the logic has to be inverted.